# NODE - Get JSON Object That Has Parentheses in Name

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I want to extract the value 921 from the following JSON:

```
[ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(mp3)': 921 } ]
```

Previously, I've been able to accomplish this with code like this: `results.thedesiredobject`. However, that method seems to be ineffective here because of the parentheses around 'mp3'.

Here's my code. I'd like to add the value of `COUNT(mp3)` (that is, 921) to the console log, rather than the entire JSON string.

```
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(mp3) FROM myverses where mp3 = "empty"', function (error, results, fields) {
  console.log('error: ' + error);
  console.log(results);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to alter my query as shown:

```
SELECT COUNT(mp3) as "total"...
```

Then, I extracted the data like this:

```
console.log(results[0].total)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
let data = { 'COUNT(mp3)': 921 }
console.log(data['COUNT(mp3)']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for this:

1) Using the javascript to get the value:

You can use the following code snippet to get the value ([Live example](http://jsbin.com/zegejoceri/edit?js,console,output))

```
const test = [ { 'COUNT(mp3)': 921 } ];
console.log(test[0]['COUNT(mp3)']);
```

2) Change your query as following:

```
'SELECT COUNT(mp3) as mp3Count FROM myverses where mp3 = "empty"'
```

This will eventually return the result with the column name as mp3Count. 
You can then use this mp3Count variable to parse the JSON response as you have stated earlier

```
results.mp3Count
```